# Strongly Continuous Group Actions on the $ C^{\ast} $-Algebra of Compact Operators on a Hilbert Space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, hilbert-spaces, group-actions

Let $ \mathcal{H} $ be a not-necessarily-separable Hilbert space. Let $ G $ be a locally compact Hausdorff group. It is easy to see that if $ U: G \to \mathbb{U}(\mathcal{H}) $ is a norm-continuous homomorphism from $ G $ to the group of unitary operators on $ \mathcal{H} $, then we can define a strongly continuous action $ \alpha $ of $ G $ on the $ C^{\ast} $-algebra $ \mathbb{K}(\mathcal{H}) $ of compact operators on $ \mathcal{H} $ by
$$
\forall g \in G: \qquad
\alpha_{g}
\stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\mathbb{K}(\mathcal{H}) & \to     & \mathbb{K}(\mathcal{H}) \\
T                       & \mapsto & U(g) \circ T \circ U(g^{-1})
\end{matrix}
\right\}.
$$

> **Question.** If $ \alpha $ is a **strongly continuous** action of $ G $ on $ \mathbb{K}(\mathcal{H}) $, does it necessarily arise from a **norm-continuous** homomorphism from $ G $ to $ \mathbb{U}(\mathcal{H}) $ as in the manner described above?

I am pretty sure that the answer to this is known already, but I am frustrated by my inability to locate a reference.

Thank you so much for your assistance!

---

**Clarification**

To avoid any confusion, I wish to clarify that a group acts on a $ C^{\ast} $-algebra by $ \ast $-automorphisms.

Comment: Obviously not, if the action of $G$ on $K(H)$ does not preserve the multiplication (i.e., is not by non-unital algebra automorphisms). Also it should commute with the $\ast$-involution. Are these missing hypotheses? The answer should be clear for $G=\mathbf{Z}$, to start with.

Comment: I have deleted my comments as they are seemingly not helpful

Comment: I am coming late to this, but as someone who is merely a practising functional analyst, it seems clear to me *from the context* of the question that the OP is asking about homomorphisms $\alpha: G \to {\rm Aut}{\mathbb K}({\mathcal H})$ where the automorphisms are in the category of ${\rm C}^*$-algebras -- which makes them isometric, $*$-preserving, non-degenerate, etc etc.

Comment: Analogy: I am quite happy talking about locally compact groups and to read other people talking about locally compact groups and have come to accept the language of "quasi-compact".

Comment: @YCor The fact that the answer is "obviously not" if we work in the generality mentioned in your first comment seems a pretty strong indication to me that the OP did not intend to work in this generality, unless you have a very low opinion of the OP's ability to check examples.

Comment: @YemonChoi please don't impugn motives. It was pretty clear from my 1st comment that I expected the OP to have implicit hypotheses, but unlike you, I wasn't sure which ones.

Comment: @YCor: I apologize for any confusion that I may have caused you. I’ve clarified in my post what I mean by a group action on a $ C^{\ast} $-algebra.

Comment: Thanks! My other question was, regardless of the topology: do you already know what is the automorphism group of $K(H)$ (as a $C^\ast$-algebra), namely, is it reduced to $U(H)$? That is, do you know the answer of your question to be positive when $G$ is discrete?

Comment: @YCor: that is correct, $U(H)$ is the automorphisms group of $K(H)$. ($K(H)$ has only one irrep up to unitary equivalence.)

Comment: @NikWeaver: Shouldn’t it be $ \mathbb{U}(\mathcal{H}) $ modulo the circle group instead?

Comment: @Transcendental: yes, you're right. (My parenthetical statement is correct as it stands.)

Comment: @Nik Oh, I forgot (and you also) to mod out by the circle group, but it's essential since it indeed yields an obstruction to lifting [this is the OP's comment to your answer]. This kind of things is why I so much insist on giving basic context! Hence, every action as given yields a map $G\to U(H)/U(1)$ and certainly the question is more interesting if one asks about continuity of this map with $U(H)/U(1)$ endowed with quotient of the norm topology. Does your proof adapt to showing this?

Comment: @YCor: yes, in my example after you factor out $U(1)$ the classes of the $U_{f_n}$ still fail to converge in the quotient of the norm topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Let $G$ be the Cartesian product of a sequence of copies of the unit circle, identified with the functions in $l^\infty$ whose modulus is constantly $1$. For $f \in G$ let $U_f \in B(l^2)$ be multiplication by $f$. Let $G$ act on $K(l^2)$ by conjugation by these unitaries.

The action is strongly continuous because convergence in $G$ is pointwise, so if $f_\alpha \to f$ and $T \in K(l^2)$ then $U_{f_\alpha}TU_{f_\alpha}^* \to U_fTU_f^*$ in norm, since $T$ approximately lives on finitely many coordinates. However, if we let $f_n$ be the function which is $-1$ in the $n$th entry and $1$ everywhere else, then $f_n \to 1$ in $G$ but $U_{f_n}$ does not go to $I$ in norm.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample, Nik! Actually, I just found out that my question has a negative answer by way of what’s called the “Mackey obstruction”. It’s an element of $ {H^{2}}(G,\mathbf{T}) $ associated to every strongly continuous action $ \alpha $ of $ G $ on $ \mathbb{K}(\mathcal{H}) $ with the property that if it isn’t trivial, then $ \alpha $ can’t be implemented by even an algebraic homomorphism from $ G $ to $ \mathbb{U}(\mathcal{H}) $, much less a norm-continuous one.

Comment: Right, I remember that now. You always get a projective unitary representation though, don't you?

Comment: Yes, we always get a projective representation.

Comment: I wonder, if I may, I could make a comment that as I see it, there are two separate things going on here.  One is the issue of projective representations.  The other is an issue of topology.  If we give $U(H)$ the SOT topology, then in Nik's example, we do have that $U_{f_n}\rightarrow 1$.  I believe that if you equip $U(H)$ with the SOT then only the cohomological obstruction is left.  I don't know how to characterise the norm-continuous case (perhaps look at actions on all of $B(H)$?)

Comment: @NikWeaver: This may sound like a silly question, Nik. Do you happen to know if every **strongly continuous** action of $ G $ on $ \mathbb{K}(\mathcal{H}) $ extends to a **strongly continuous** action of $ G $ on $ \mathbb{B}(\mathcal{H}) $? I’m assuming $ G $ to be an arbitrary locally compact Hausdorff group.